# How to give config property to a view Item in Extjs 6?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-modern

In Extjs 6 how to assign a config property directly to a view either through binding or direct assignment?

```
Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

config: {
    btnLabel: 'MyButton'
},

someOtherProperty:'xyz',

items: [{
    xtype:'button',

    //text:this.someOtherProperty,
    //text:this.btnLabel,
    //text:this.getBtnLabel(),

    //here accessing this throws error, while loading this refers to windows object and not the class... 
    width:'150px'
    }],
});
```

i can move the property to ViewModel and access it but my question is this, can't we assign the class level property to its child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not like that you can't. The problem is that you're defining the items in the class prototype - which means you can't do anything specific to the instance there.

That's what `initComponent` is for. I typically define my `items` attribute there, expressly for this purpose:

```
Ext.define('App.view.main.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  config: {
    btnLabel: 'MyButton'
  },
  someOtherProperty:'xyz',

  initComponent: function() {
    // The config properties have already been transferred to the instance
    // during the class construction, prior to initComponent being called.
    // That means we can now call this.getBtnLabel()
    this.items = [
      { xtype: 'button',
        text: this.getBtnLabel(),
        width:'150px'
    }]

    // Call the parent function as well. NB: After this, items won't be
    // a simple array anymore - it gets changed into a collection of
    // components.
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

In general, be careful adding objects in as class level properties, as they will be properties on the prototype and shared amongst all instances of that class.